# create folders when the picture is uploaded laravel

Tags: laravel, path, upload, directory

I want to save the uploads from the users in a path with the user ID. How can I integrate the ID into the path that automatically creates the folder?

```
if($r->hasFile('avatar'))

  {
    Auth::user()->update([
      'avatar'=> $r->avatar->store('public/$id/avatar')
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) if you want your id variable to be interpolated there:

```
'avatar'=> $r->avatar->store("public/$id/avatar")
```

Comment: Then you can set it, earlier in your code, with `$id = Auth::id();`. But you might prefer `->store('public/' . Auth::id() . '/avatar/filename.jpg');`